# Class not exist in symfony 2, but all seem correct

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a strange problem. I have an error like this

> Class Backend\GruposAlumnosBundle\Entity\GruposAlumnos does not exist
>   in F:\wamp\www\getbritSys\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php at line 233

```php
   }
   // We need to pick the type hint class too
   if (($paramClass = $param->getClass()) !== null) {
       $parameterString .= '\\' . $paramClass->getName() . ' ';
   } else if ($param->isArray()) {
       $parameterString .= 'array ';*
```

This error occurs when I do this in my controller

```php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$grupoalumno = $em->getRepository('BackendGruposBundle:GruposAlumnos')->find($item);
```

and my entity class `GruposAlumnos` exists in the `BackendGruposBundle`.

Some ideas? I don't find the problem and it is quite rare

(`BackendGruposBundle` is loaded in `AppKernel`. It is checked. This bundle have more entities with theirs controllers and work correctly)

Comment: Did you forget the namespace in `GruposAlumnos.php` ?

Comment: Is your bundle named BackendGruposBundle or BackendGruposAlumnosBundle? In the getRepository() call, you missed 'Alumnos'.

Comment: In my class GruposAlumnos I have this namespace Backend\GruposBundle\Entity;

Comment: My Bundle is named BackendGruposBundle, the entity is named GruposAlumnos. Other entities in this bundle are named Grupo, ...

Comment: @Freenando I see you solved the problem, could you please add this as an answer and accept that accept after 48 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this error.
This error comes from methods `addEntity` and `removeEntity` from the relationships. I had defined with wrong parameters.
I think this error would be more explicit.